# Close a Page Sheet VC through pulling in down

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to close a VC on a special way.
As the title says I want it to be covered vertical but not from down to top, but the other way.
i tried all things I found but non of them helped. I´m using Navigation controllers and if I pull the VC with my finger down it works, but if I use my back Btn it covers from bottom to top.

Currently the button code is pretty simple:
`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToFriends", sender: nil)`
Where do I have to define In which way it closes?

Thanks for every help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ups it´s really simple.
Just using `self.dismiss(animated: true)` and that´s it